# How to Load an image in an activity in android.

Tags: android

This code save the image in " MyApp ".but how to load the image in other activity

```
final EditText txtRegid = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.regid);
     String RegID = txtRegid.getText().toString();

     Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        File mImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyApp",  
                "PIC"+RegID+".jpg");
      String mSelectedImagePath = mImageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mImageFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have defined the BitMap variable as a data member of your MyApp class, you can easily fetch it in other activities by using a `getter() function` to fetch that BitMap image which you are storing in MyApp.

Or, you could pass your image along with Intent, by encoding it into  String format.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the absolute path of the file. You can use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, opts)` method to get the Bitmap. Then use ImageView's method setImageBitmap() to show it.